# Do you have experience with AMOLED displays?

Tags: display

Any one have experience with AMOLED displays. Are they better than current LED monitors for coding?

When are [these](http://www.careace.net/2010/05/07/iron-man-2-cellphone-coming-to-samsung/) going to hit the retail/on-line stores?

Comment: AMOLEDs for computer displays.. are not yet available as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

I have tried Samsung Galaxy Android phone which has AMOLED displays technology. Unfortunately I sold the device after one week since it was too bright, even under lowest contrast level. I usually have the display on lowest contrast since I put a lot of time in front of the computer screen. A high contrast value is very annoying for my eyes. If you are going to use your computer in dark environment under long hours then you should consider this. The picture, quality/contrast/colour are however amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Galaxy S (Captivate) and find it to be fine for my personal tastes on the low settings. And, added benefit, when you are outside you can put the setting up higher, and it is **brilliantly** visible even in outdoor lighting (though of course this drains the battery quicker). Plus, AMOLEDs supposedly use no energy to show the color black.  :)